# Newton Raphson Method for maximizing log likelihood function from Item Response Theory

Tags: matrices, parameter-estimation, newton-raphson

I am currently working on a modified version of the [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5360254&tag=1). In section V-B, I am stuck on the Item-Parameter Estimation of the Log-Likelihood function for the [Item-Response Theory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory).

I will briefly summarize the problem as stated in the paper.

Given the log-likelihood function,

$$L=\sum_{g=1}^K[r_{ig} logP_i(\theta_{g})+ (f_g-r_{ig})log(1-P_i(\theta_g))]$$

where$$P_{ij}=\frac {1}{1+e^{-\alpha_i(\theta_j-\beta_i)}}$$

find the item parameters $\xi_i=(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$  that maximize the log-likelihood function.

For this the Newton-Raphson method is used, which, given the partial derivatives

$L_1=\frac {\partial L}{\partial \alpha_i}$ , $L_2=\frac {\partial L}{\partial \beta_i}$ , $L_{11}=\frac {\partial^2 L}{\partial \alpha_i^2}$ , $L_{22}=\frac {\partial^2 L}{\partial \beta_i^2}$ , $L_{12}=L_{21}=\frac {\partial^2 L}{\partial \alpha_i\beta_i}$

estimates the parameters iteratively as follows:

$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
\hat{\alpha_i}\\
\hat{\beta_i}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]_{t+1} = 
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
\hat{\alpha_i}\\
\hat{\beta_i}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]_{t} - 
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
L_{11}&L_{12}\\
L_{21}&L_{22}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]_{t}^{-1} 
\times
\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
L_{1}\\
L_{2}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]_{t}
$$

Now, each of the above partial derivatives would be some N dimensional vector. How does one go about evaluating the inverse and subsequently a multiplication of such a matrix? Moreover, will solving the equation for each $i^{th}$ entity separately be the same as solving the entire equation in one go?

Last, (Assuming I am permitted to ask this question here), are there any packages available in (Python/Matlab/Java/C++) that can help to implement the above solution conveniently?

Thanks in advance.